# R: Shiny - Plot visits by source for month selected

Tags: r, shiny

I cannot plot a simply barplot in Shiny for a specific month selected.

I've a data frame like this one: (for October, November and Dicember)

```
      month  Campanas1     Visitas
1   Octubre  Directo        9126
2   Octubre  Email          5753
3   Octubre  Referencias    75678
4   Octubre  SEO            81266
5   Octubre  Social Media   109
```

Then I want to make an Shiny-App that shows the visits by source when a month is selected. This are my Shiny files:

My     ui.R:

```
# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    

# Give the page a title
titlePanel("Visitas por fuente"),

# Generate a row with a sidebar
sidebarLayout(      

  # Define the sidebar with one input



  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("mes", "Mes:", 
                choices=as.character(unique(Visitas_Por_Fuente$month))),
    hr(),
    helpText("Seleccione el rango de fechas para ver la cantidad de visitas 
             totales.")
  ),

  # Create a spot for the barplot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("VisitasFuente")  
     )

   )
  )
)
```

My server.R file:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

     barplot(Visitas_Por_Fuente$Campanas1)

    })

  }
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are trying to plot on variable Compansa1, which is not possible as bar plot can only be plotted on vector or matrix.

Secondly, You could probably use ggplot instead to get better visuals. Also you'll have to filter your data frame based on user choice of month.

***Your server.R file should look as below:***

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

    # Filter the data based on user selection month     
    appData <- Visitas_Por_Fuente[Visitas_Por_Fuente$month %in% input$mes, ]

     # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
     ggplot(appData, aes(factor(Campanas1), Visitas, fill = Campanas1)) + 
            geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
            scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9"),
                              labels = c("Directo", "Email", "References",
                                         "SEO", "Social Media"),
                              values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                         "#F0E442", "#0072B2"))
    })
  }
 )
```

***Output of `runApp()`:***

[image: ShinyOutput]

Comment: Thanks, @Manohar S. It works perfect. How ever, when should i use ggplot2 vs ggvis within Shiny? Is there any clear advantage?

Comment: also when there are new variables the colors that difference the source "Campanas" changes. E.G, in October SEO is purple, but in Dicember it is yellow. How can i keep a standar?

Comment: ggvis is for creating interactive plots and better suits shiny apps, however ggvis API is currently rapidly evolving. So recommend that you do not rely on this for production, but feel free to explore. If you’re familiar with ggplot2, learning ggvis shouldn’t be too hard - it borrows from many familiar concepts. I have now edited the answer to use `scale_fill_manual` in `ggplot` to keep the colors standard.